# How to request a portion of a webpage scrapy (python)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am a bit new to web scraping and my question might be a bit silly. I want to get information from a rental website. I want to **scrape** almost 2000 pages per day to obtain the information. But I do not want to hammer their website. I just need information inside a specific  tag which is a table. Is there any ways to only request that part of the page rather than getting the whole page?

I will surely add delay and sleep to the script, but reducing file size would also help.
Implementing that will reduce the requested file size from around 300kB to 11kB.

Website URL: https://asunnot.oikotie.fi/vuokrattavat-asunnot

example of webpage: https://asunnot.oikotie.fi/vuokrattavat-asunnot/imatra/15733776

required tag: `<div class="listing-details-container">...</div>`

Thank you for your response in advance :)

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no ways to request portion of HTML...

Comment: There will be one in the upcoming Scrapy 2.2, however I don’t think it should be used for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I think 2000 a day is not high - depends when you do it.  If you put a 10 second wait between each request that should not overload it - but would take 6 hours.
It may be better to do it overnight when the site should be quieter.
If you do 2000 with no wait the site owner may be unhappy.

Comment: Great suggestions, thanks! I will do so.
I wanted to also reduce the amount of traffic to improve the speed of the process. Their website contains lots of images that I do not need.